# How to get total sum

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables.

```
Sales
------

ID    Charge    VAT
1     100      10
2     200      20


SaleProducts
------------

ID  Product    Auto   SalesID
1   aa         True   1 
2   bb         False  1
```

I want to get this

```
SaleOnProduct
-------------

ID    Product     Charge     VAT    Total   TotalAmount(All of total is plus)
1     aa          100        10     110     220  
2     aa          100        10     110     220
```

How can I do this. Please help me.

Comment: What you mean by "TotalAmount(All of total is plus)"?

Comment: This does not look correct...

Comment: What you are expecting seems to be incorrect. The total should be 330 and the second row should have been (2,bb,200,20,220, 330).

Comment: yes, TotalAmount is plused all of total.

Comment: @zanhtet Did you try my modified query below.

Comment: @zanhet i.e. TotalAmount = (Charge + Vat) * 2 ?

Comment: @zanhet See, your question raises many other questions, which (I guess) are not related to your true question: I suspect, your intention was to know, how to join (or union) two tables into one result?

Comment: No, I want to get all of adding charge and vat.

Comment: @zanhtet In the *I want to get this* table BOTH of your rows specify product aa, is that what you want? Duplicate rows? One for each sale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @Sales table (ID int, Charge int, VAT int)
declare @SaleProducts table (ID int, Product char(2), Auto bit, SalesID int)

insert into @Sales values
(1, 100, 10),
(2, 200, 20)

insert into @SaleProducts values
(1, 'aa', 1, 1),
(2, 'bb', 0, 1)

select 
  SP.ID, 
  SP.Product,
  S.Charge,
  S.VAT,
  S.Charge+S.VAT as Total,
  sum(S.Charge+S.VAT) over() as TotalAmount
from @Sales as S
  inner join @SaleProducts as SP
    on S.ID = SP.SalesID
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get data from both tables in the same resultset you need to do a join.

Since you want to have a summary row for all sales ((charge+VAT)*numberofSaleProductsRows) of each particular product, you need to use the SUM aggregate funciton, and a GROUP BY clause. All the columns which you need in your resultset and which do not have a specified aggregation needs to be included in the GROUP BY list.

Disclaimer: Untested code

```
 SELECT ID, Product, Charge ,VAT, Charge + VAT as Total, 
            Sum(Charge + VAT) as TotalAmount
 FROM Sales INNER JOIN SaleProducts 
           ON Sales.ID = SaleProducts.SalesID
 GROUP BY ID, Product, Charge, VAT, Charge + VAT
```

Answer (score 0):

This query do the job: (I supposed SQL Server 2005 or above, otherwise you´ve to change the cte by a temp table)

```
WITH ReportCte as(
SELECT  b.Id IdSale,
        a.Id IdProduct,
        a.Product,
        b.Charge,
        b.VAT,
        b.Charge+b.VAT Total
  FROM  [dbo].[SaleProducts] a left join
        [dbo].[Sales] b on a.[SalesID] = b.ID)
SELECT  a.IdProduct,
        a.IdProduct,
        a.Charge,
        a.VAT,
        a.Total,
        b.TotalAmount
FROM    ReportCte a left join
        (select IdSale,SUM(Total) TotalAmount 
        from ReportCte group by IdSale) b on a.IdSale=b.IdSale
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select *, (charge+VAT) as total, SUM(charge+VAT) as totalAmount
from sales
join saleproducts on sales.ID=saleproducts.salesID
group by sales.ID
```

Comment: It has serious syntax problems. If you´re grouping you have to consider an aggregation function for each column of * except sales.ID (Charge, VAT, etc).